# Is there a way to get more information for a Steam game through API like ratings or tags?

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I know that you can get quite a lot of information with calling:

http://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=57690

But it is still missing data which available on the store page like rating, tags, etc. is there a parameter or another way to get more information about a game?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can extract ratings information with the [Steamworks User Reviews - Get List endpoint](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/store/getreviews).

For example, to get info about CS:GO:

> GET https://store.steampowered.com/appreviews/10?json=1&language=all

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "query_summary": {
    "num_reviews": 20,
    "review_score": 9,
    "review_score_desc": "Overwhelmingly Positive",
    "total_positive": 25703,
    "total_negative": 898,
    "total_reviews": 26601
  },
  "reviews": [
    {
      "recommendationid": "122478997",
      "author": {
        "steamid": "76561198072280507",
        "num_games_owned": 3,
        "num_reviews": 2,
        "playtime_forever": 503225,
        "playtime_last_two_weeks": 0,
        "playtime_at_review": 503224,
        "last_played": 1663589422
      },
      "language": "english",
      "review": "God dam what a game",
      "timestamp_created": 1663588856,
      "timestamp_updated": 1663588856,
      "voted_up": true,
      "votes_up": 11,
      "votes_funny": 2,
      "weighted_vote_score": "0.643105804920196533",
      "comment_count": 0,
      "steam_purchase": true,
      "received_for_free": false,
      "written_during_early_access": false,
      "hidden_in_steam_china": true,
      "steam_china_location": ""
    }
  ],
  "cursor": "AoIFP+vAcEAAAAB6htXVAw=="
}
```

The `query_summary` returns global rating information about the game.

Comment: Thank you for adding this, looks great. Do you know a similar for tags? I couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't a public api endpoint for rating/tags etc.

The link you send isn't even officially supported by Valve as an API endpoint and is rate limited.

You can read through **[here](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi)** for all the API endpoints of Steam, but the one you are using now is the only one with most of the game data in detail.

Comment: I understand that it is rate limited - as I know the Web API too - but what do you mean by _not officially supported_?